# Dell poweredge R620 RAM Population

Tags: memory, dell-poweredge

In my Dell poweredge R620 server i install 8GB 12 Memory stick in slot B1-B12,but some memory stick not showing(B5,B6,B9,B10),server usable memory is 64gb now.Plz suggest me RAM population.

Edit:All RAM are same configuratin(8gb,2Rx4,DDR3 PC3L-10600R 1333MHZ)
                OS-Windows Server 2012 Standard

Comment: That seems like a hardware issue based on the computer's specs.  Try the ones that don't work in the slots that already work or the opposite to see if the result changes.  I suspect you will find out that either the sticks or the slots are bad, or that they are not properly inserted.

Answer (score 0):

There are specific memory population guidelines for your Server

Refer page 40-49 for more information. The Service Manual can be downloaded from the below link.

The existing is a Dual Rank Registered ECC modules, and I hope you're installing in the B1-B12 slots, after populating in the A1-A12 Slots.

http://downloads.dell.com/manuals/all-products/esuprt_ser_stor_net/esuprt_poweredge/poweredge-r620_owner%27s%20manual_en-us.pdf